# WP8 Parse send push notification with custom Param

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

From [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx), I see that I can send a toast notification that opens a specific page when user taps it, which is what I want. The push message should be like this:

```
string message = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                    "<wp:Toast>" +
                        "<wp:Text1>title</wp:Text1>" +
                        "<wp:Text2>message</wp:Text2>" +
                        "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast</wp:Param>" +
                    "</wp:Toast>" +
                "</wp:Notification>";
```

Equivalently in Parse (I'm not 100% sure):

```
push.Data = new Dictionary<string, object>{
                    {"title", "title"},
                    {"alert", "message"},
                    {"param", "/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast"}
                };
```

The toast is displayed correctly when my app is closed. But tapping it always open the **default page** instead of **Page2.xaml**. And Parse seems to replace my "param" string with a very long string. Something like this:

```
    {[wp:Param, ?pushJson=%7B%22title%22:%22title%22,%22alert%22:%22message%22,%22param%22:%22/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast%22,%22push_hash%22:%2278e731027d8fd50ed642340b7c9a63b3%22%7D]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>
```

So how can I make the toast to open **Page2.xaml** on tap?

Comment: Did u get any solution? Even I am trying to send Param but unable to figure our how to deep link the push notification to a specific page in the app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find any solution until now. I think it is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Sadly the only way to add custom data in a Windows push is to embed them in wp:Param. This is funny because in this way is pretty unuseful, because these data can only be retrieved via ParsePush.ToastNotificationReceived, that obviously works only if the app is running in the foreground.